# The new ASP.NET Core 3.0 Json serializer is leaving out data

Tags: asp.net-core, jsonserializer, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm porting a web application to ASP.NET Core 3, and after a bit of a battle, I'm almost at the finish line. Everything seems to work, but all of a sudden my JSON data returned from the api is missing some levels.

It seems the `options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth` is default at 64 levels, so it can be that. Some other places where an option can be playing tricks on me?

This is the code (and a quickview of the value):

[image]

[image]

And this is the JSON I get in the browser:

[image]

So the ParticipantGroups property/collection is completely missing in the generated output.

Any ideas where this happens?

**EDIT:**

I've added a repo on Github that showcases the issue. Standard ASP.NET Core 3.0 solution, created from the template, with a change to the result returned from the Weatherforecast controller:

https://github.com/steentottrup/systemtextjsonissue

Comment: Please show your code/JSON as text, not images. And includes the relevant class definitions in your question (again, as Text).

Answer (score 2):

For now I've gone back to using Newtonsoft.Json, with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package. Then when I have some time, I'll try finding out what the solution is, without Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: This is not an answer IMO, to this question. This is just _what you have done_ to keep working. I would delete this 'answer' because it's not really helping. When you get a chance, I would also try and update the initial post with some more code examples so we can all try and help you some more.

Comment: I haven't accepted it for exactly that reason, but for some, like myself at the moment, this might be the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Pure.Krome in .Net 6 `System.Text.Json` still does not have 100% parity with `Newtonsoft`. If you have issues with `System.Text.Json`, then switching to `Newtonsoft` instead is still a viable and acceptable solution. OP didn't ask specifically for a solution that uses `System.Text.Json`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be an error in the new version 3.0. At least it seems like an error to me.

It seems `System.Text.Json` will convert the class mentioned in the hierarchy, not the  actual class. So if you are using an abstract class in the hierarchy, you're in trouble. The second I removed the base class, and used the actual class I'm returning, the problem goes away it seems.

So this doesn't work:

```
public class SurveyReportResult {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrganisationalUnit> OrganisationalUnits { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OrganisationalUnit {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }

}

public class OrganisationalUnitWithParticipantGroups : OrganisationalUnit {
    public IEnumerable<ParticipantGroup> ParticipantGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantGroup {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }
}
```

This will only return the properties of the `OrganisationalUnit` class, not the additional property of the `OrganisationalUnitWithParticipantGroups`.

This works:

```
public class SurveyReportResult {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrganisationalUnitWithParticipantGroups> OrganisationalUnits { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationalUnitWithParticipantGroups /*: OrganisationalUnit*/ {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParticipantGroup> ParticipantGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantGroup {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MemberCount { get; set; }
}
```